# Bitbucket authentication to use LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket, libgit2sharp, bitbucket-api

I used the CSharp.Bitbucket library to authenticate users with Bitbucket (https://github.com/scottksmith95/CSharp.Bitbucket). 
The authentication works fine, I get the token value and token secret values.

I have alredy written a logic - with the help of LibGit2Sharp (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) - to clone/pull/push the content of the users repo. It works fine if the user authenticates with GitHub. In that case I have to provide the value of the access token for username and an empty string for password.

```
 LibGit2Sharp.Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
        {
            Username = [GITHUB ACCESS TOKEN], 
            Password =""
        };
```

But what about Bitbucket? Can I use LibGit2Sharp in this way? I couldn't find any documentation about this issue. I tried to use the token value and the token secret also for username, but it fails.

[image]

I would like to use Bitbucket with Git and Mercurial too. Is there a little trick which I couldn't realize this far?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way of passing the token as the username with a blank password is specific to GitHub AFAIK (**[see this help article](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens#step-2-clone-a-repository)**). The article also states that passing `x-oauth-basic` works.

The BitBucket issue **[#7735](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7735/allow-http-access-to-repositories-via)** seems to state that passing the token as the username and `x-oauth-basic` would also work.

Comment: The access token has a value and a secret as well. I tried both of these (and leave the Password variable blank) but I have got the following error message.
What do you think, what did I wrong?

Comment: It may be worth sending an email to support@bitbucket.org

Answer (score 4):

This question is old but I will answer for those how come across whith this problem.
First, what you have to do is get an acces token.
Its well explaned [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html).

Once you have the token, you can authenticate like this

```or-tag-here
   CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
        {
            Username = x-token-auth:[ACCES-TOKEN],
            Password = ""
        }
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Its not working for me. I am getting error "too many redirects or authentication replays"

Comment: Same, I'm seeing the too many redirects error

Answer (score 1):

[2022] You can use `LibGit2Sharp` even for `Bitbucket` but you don't need any tokens. There is a little bit different flow by using app password. (This works even with
2FA enabled.)

1. In the bitbucket go to:

   - `https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/`
   - or manually navigate:
     `Click your picture -> Personal settings -> App passwords`
2. Click `Create app password`

   - Name it after the service in which you will use it/or for what purpose
   - Add needed permissions
   - hit create
3. Find your bitbucket name:

   - navigate to `https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/`
   - or `Click your picture -> Personal settings -> Account settings`
   - and in sub-category `Bitbucket profile settings` is your `Username`
4. apply these credentials to your code. E.g.

   ```
   var url = "https://bitbucket.org/<user_or_org_name>/<repository_name>.git";
   var Username = "<your_user_name>";
   var Password = "<your_app_password>";
   var localPathForRepository = @"D:\temp";

   var creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
   {
       Username = Username,
       Password = Password
   };

   CredentialsHandler credHandler = (_url, _user, _cred) => creds;

   bool dirExists = Directory.Exists(localPathForRepository);
   if (dirExists)
   {
       Directory.Delete(localPathForRepository, true);
   }
   Directory.CreateDirectory(localPathForRepository);

   var cloneOptions = new CloneOptions { BranchName = "master", Checkout = true, CredentialsProvider = credHandler };
   var cloneResult = Repository.Clone(url, localPathForRepository, cloneOptions);
   ```
5. DONE

**Sources:**

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/

https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens

https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/#Use-an-API-token