# how to clone GitHub repo locally via libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, libgit2sharp

I wrote code to programmatically clone a GitHub private repo to a local repo via libgit2sharp ( v0.21.0.176 )

```
var cloneOptions = new CloneOptions { BranchName = "master", Checkout = true };
var cloneResult = Repository.Clone( @"https://github.com/my-organization/my-repo.git", @"c:\github\my-organization\my-repo" );
```

exception thrown :

```
{LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Request failed with status code: 401
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
```

cloneResult value is null ( never set due to exception thrown )

Note that the identical 401 exception is thrown whether or not the \my-repo\ folder is present.

Is my function call syntax correct ?

Executed from the command line, `git clone` first creates a local dir folder to clone into.

Does libgit2sharp `Repository.Clone()` work differently ?

Comment: mods : shouldn't down-votes be required to leave a comment explaining why ? i don't see what's wrong with my question

Comment: Due to the '\', perhaps you should use a verbatim string for the path by prefixing it with `@`

Comment: Your exception stack trace doesn't seem to match Your code sample. What version of LibGit2Sharp are tyou leveraging? What does `cloneResult` contain?

Comment: Very strange but the stack-trace I originally posted is incorrect. I've updated with correct stack-trace and libgit2sharp version v0.21.0.176.  Because exception thrown, `cloneResult` is never set and so its value remains null.  The paths are actually dynamically generated, but I tried with static-paths @"{path}" and the same exception was thrown.

Comment: Here you have a working example with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72602335/6158341

Answer (score 5, accepted):

401 is the HTTP code meaning that you need to authenticate against the server. There are code paths in libgit2 which do not always correctly convert this situation into `GIT_AUTH`, but that's what it means.

GitHub (and other services) can also return this error when the repository does not exist, as a way to avoid leaking information about the existence of private repositories.

You're not providing any way for libgit2(sharp) to ask you for the user's credentials. You need to pass in `CloneOptions` where you have a `CredentialsProvider` set to an authorized user's credentials.

Comment: bin folder does not download while cloning